# GUILayout --- How to change text font & size of a (text) variable

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to directly change the font size of the text in an *editable* text box?

I have a tutorial stage where a message is displayed at the end when the user completes the tutorial.

I call this message `endingText` which is defined in my `TutorialDefinition` script:

```
string endingText = "You have completed the tutorial stage!";
```

In another script called `TutorialEditor`, I initialize it with the text that the user can input through the `Editor`. So, the `endingText` variable is there in the `Definition` script in case the user did not input anyhing...

```
void initValues()
{
   endingText = stage.EndingText;
}
```

And finally, when the tutorial is done through the `TutorialExecutor`, I show the message, using:

```
endingText = GUILayout.TextArea( endingText );
```

The `font` and `font size` are set somewhere else through the current `skin` I think, but I wonder if it is possible to directly manipulate the above code snippet and change the font size? 
I mean this line of code: `endingText = GUILayout.TextArea( endingText );` that will eventually show the user the final message through `void OnGUI()` method...

(I understand I could if, instead of `endingText`, there was actual text within `""` but what about now?)

Comment: are you using the new gui (4.6+) or the old gui?

Comment: I am using Unity 4.6 Pro but the old GUI.